# Structuremap - Caching a single object instance for all request

Tags: structuremap

if I want StructureMap to return a single object instance for all
requests, is there any difference at all between the two methods
below??

```
StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => {x
   .ForRequestedType<ISplitPaymentConfigurationReader>()
   .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SplitPaymentConfigurationReader>()
   .CacheBy(StructureMap.Attributes.InstanceScope.Singleton);
});
```

and

```
StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Inject<ISplitPaymentConfigurationReader>(
 new SplitPaymentConfigurationReader());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by the great folks in StructureMap, the two are the same, except that with the first way, you get auto-wiring of dependencies, where you don't with the second way.